# Knockoutjs, jquery mobile slider

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider, knockout.js

I was wondering if someone had a working example of JQM slider with knockoutjs.  I have 2 issues:

1) binding the value to an observable - I can bind it initially i.e. set the "value" of the slider, but this does not update the underlying observable when dragged - I think that this is to do with JQM putting elements over the input to represent it?

2) refreshing the style when changing the min, max, value properties.

Here is a subset of what I have, currentItems changes based on a selection:

```
workloadViewModel.filterValues = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
var tmp = {};
var itms = this.currentItems();

if (itms.length == 0) return;

tmp.max = itms[0].val;
tmp.min = itms[itms.length - 1].val;
tmp.minRange = this.minRange();

return tmp;
}, workloadViewModel);


ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRefreshSlider = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //just to create a dependency
    try {
        $("input[type=range]").slider("refresh");            
    } catch (error) {
        trace("error refreshing slider");
    }
}
};

<div id="filters" data-bind="template: {name: 'filterTemplate', data: filterValues}, jqmRefreshSlider: filterValues"></div>

<script id='filterTemplate' type='text/html'>        

    <p>min: ${minRange}</p>
    <p>min: ${min}</p>
    <p>max: ${max}</p>
    <div>
        <input type="range" name="slider_min" id="slider_min" value="${minRange}" min="${min}" max="${max}" />
    </div>
</script>
```

Thanks you very much for any help you can give me.

J

Comment: I was wondering, by "half the problem" whether you referring to binding not all slider options like min and max. If that is the case, let me know if you've came to a solution which covers all the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working binding to silder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var val = valueAccessor()();
        $(element).slider(
                            {
                                value: val,
                                step: 3,
                                slide: function (event, ui) {
                                    valueAccessor()(ui.value);
                                }
                            });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).slider("option", "value", valueAccessor()());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

none of the above worked for me because my slider was being added dynamically

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span data-bind="text: test"></span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="c-slider" >
  <!-- ko if: is -->
   <input id="test-i" type="range" min="1" max="10" data-bind="value: test, slider: test" />
  <!-- /ko -->

  </div>
  <input id="test-t" type="text"  data-bind="value: test" />
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function model() {
    var self = this;
    self.test = ko.observable("1");
    self.test.subscribe(function(v) {
    alert('s');
    $("#test-i").val(v).slider('refresh');
 });
self.is = ko.observable(true);
 }

 ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
   var value = valueAccessor();
   $(document).on({
    "mouseup touchend": function (elem) {
     value($('#' + element.id).val());
    }
   }, ".c-slider");
  }
 };

 var m = new model();
 ko.applyBindings(m);
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was gnashing my teeth for a couple days with the JQM slider.  Finally I was able to get true 2-way binding to an observable for the slider's value, and have it update both the thumb slider and the numeric range input.  Here is what I came up with:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // use setTimeout with 0 to run this after Knockout is done
        setTimeout(function () {
            // $(element) doesn't work as that has been removed from the DOM
            var curSlider = $('#' + element.id);
            // helper function that updates the slider and refreshes the thumb location
            function setSliderValue(newValue) {
                curSlider.val(newValue).slider('refresh');
            }
            // subscribe to the bound observable and update the slider when it changes
            valueAccessor().subscribe(setSliderValue);
            // set up the initial value, which of course is NOT stored in curSlider, but the original element :\
            setSliderValue($(element).val());
            // subscribe to the slider's change event and update the bound observable
            curSlider.bind('change', function () {
                valueAccessor()(curSlider.val());
            });
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

And here is how it is used in the HTML:

```
<input type="range" data-bind="value: currentLineWidth, slider: currentLineWidth" name="penSizeSlider" id="penSizeSlider" min="1" max="150" />
```

I have updated my Blog with this information as well.  More info about integrating Knockout and JQuery Mobile can be found there.
http://www.programico.com/1/post/2012/12/knockoutjs-jquerymobile-slider.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  For fellow web noobs, I'll add that you need to make sure that your slider input has an id set.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. It also handles dynamically created elements. It's a bit hacky though. I've reused some code from [Knockoutjs (version 2.1.0): bind boolean value to select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510683/knockoutjs-version-2-1-0-bind-boolean-value-to-select-box) for autotically handling parsing strings to bools and vice versa:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmFlip = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            interceptor = ko.computed({
                read: function() {
                    return observable().toString();
                },
                write: function(newValue) {
                    observable(newValue === "true");
                }
            });

        var result = ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor });

        try {
            $(element).slider("refresh");
        } catch(x) {

            $(element).next('.ui-slider').remove();
            $(element).slider();
            /*console.log('jqmFlip init error ' + x);*/
        }
        return result;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update.apply(this, arguments);
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        try {
            $(element).slider("refresh");
        } catch(x) {
            debugger;
            console.log('jqmFlip update error ' + x);
        }
    }
};
```