# knockout.js data-binding to dropdown overwrites original value

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, observable

I have a function that puts an object into an observable called "detailedStudent" which will display some of the student's fields in a modal.  Here's the problem:

1. I start with a field that has a value of false. (IncludeInStudentSiteResults)
2. I set the 'student' object inside 'detailedStudent' which displays the dropdown list (simulating a modal popup).
3. The field's value gets set to true, which is the first option in the dropdown list.

Here's a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/62fDB/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown option values are strings (not booleans).
Update your data initialization like so

```
...
"IncludeInStudentSiteResults": "false",
...
```

JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/62fDB/22/

or use a solution from the following post [Knockoutjs (version 2.1.0): bind boolean value to select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510683/knockoutjs-version-2-1-0-bind-boolean-value-to-select-box)

Comment: This is certainly helpful and a step in the right direction, but the boolean value is getting automatically serialized into JSON as a boolean.  Is there a preferred way of having booleans as dropdown option values?

Comment: This might help [Knockoutjs (version 2.1.0): bind boolean value to select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510683/knockoutjs-version-2-1-0-bind-boolean-value-to-select-box)

Answer (score 0):

This is your version:

```
function StudentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.students = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.detailedStudent = ko.observable();

    this.clickMe = function(student) {
        alert(student.IncludeInStudentSiteResults());
        self.detailedStudent(student);
        alert(student.IncludeInStudentSiteResults());
    }
}​
```

Try to use my version:

```
function StudentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.students = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.detailedStudent = ko.observable();

    this.clickMe = function(student) {
        alert(student.IncludeInStudentSiteResults());
        self.detailedStudent(ko.observable(student));
        alert(student.IncludeInStudentSiteResults());
    }
}​
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62fDB/23/

Comment: The issue with your version is that the detailedStudent never gets bound and thus the dropdown never appears on the page.

Comment: Using your updated fix, I get a pretty common console JavaScript error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: IncludeInStudentSiteResults is not defined; Bindings value: value: IncludeInStudentSiteResults

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that contains the answer to my question.  I don't love that I had to write a custom binding, but the alternative would be to use an enum instead of data-binding to a boolean.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekyDh/2/